# Need to convert integer to random integer in PYTHON

Tags: python

I need to convert the code for generating an integer with a hash TO generating a random integer from a range with a hash.

```
return int(my_hash, 16)
 switch to randint(0000, 9999)with hash
 #need a random int from a specific range of integers
```

Comment: can you not do `int_var = random.randint(#range of numbers)` for some reason?

Comment: what is my_hash value?

Answer (score 0):

built in random has a randrange(n) function which should give you what you want.

```
randInt = random.randrange(9999)
```

Then you can apply your hash to it.